# ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python

Checked the other answers for similar problems, but couldn't find anything that solved this particular problem.  I can't figure out why I'm getting error, because I don't believe I'm missing any values.  Also, I think it's odd that it says line 1 column 1 (char 0) - any of you wonderful people have any ideas?

```
import json
import urllib.request

user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7"

url = "http://api.usatoday.com/open/articles/topnews?encoding=json&api_key=98jv5a93qs"

headers={"User-Agent":user_agent,} 

request = urllib.request.Request(url, None, headers)

parsed_json = json.loads(str(request))

for i in range(6):
    title = parsed_json['stories'][i]['title']
    link = parsed_json['stories'][i]['link']
    print(title)
    print(link)
    print("-----------------------------------")
```

Comment: Have you verified that the value of `response` contains JSON?

Comment: Oh jeez, no! Rookie mistake.  I guess that api url isn't active any longer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to parse the response JSON. but you didn't event sent the request.
you should send your `Request` and then parse the response JSON:

```
import json
import urllib.request

user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7"

url = "http://api.usatoday.com/open/articles/topnews?encoding=json&api_key=98jv5a93qs"

headers={"User-Agent":user_agent,}

request = urllib.request.Request(url, None, headers)
res = urllib.request.urlopen(request)

parsed_json = json.loads(res.readall())

for i in range(6):
    title = parsed_json['stories'][i]['title']
    link = parsed_json['stories'][i]['link']
    print(title)
    print(link)
    print("-----------------------------------")
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen in [both the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) ([or v. 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)) and at the URL above, the issue is that you are trying to parse JSON which is not JSON. I suggest wrapping your call to `json.loads` in a try... except block and handle bad JSON. This is generally good practice anyway.

For good measure I looked up the [source code for the `json` module](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0a1266ef1b5d/Modules/_json.c). It looks like all errors from Py2k point to value errors, thought I could not find the specific error you mention.

Based on my read of [the JSON module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/829b49cbd2e4b1d573470da79ca844b730120f3d/Lib/json/decoder.py), you'll also be able to get more information if you use `try...except` and print the properties of the error module as well.